# Include implementation file inside namespace to avoid name clashing

Tags: c++, namespaces, include

I am making a C++ wrapper around a C library. Let's say that the library (let's call it Clib) defines a function like this:

```c
// clib.h
const char* clib_foo(clib_obj_t* obj);
```

In my wrapper I have the following:

```cpp
// clibpp.h
#include <clib.h>

namespace clib {
    std::string_view foo(const clib::obj_t& obj) {
        return clib_foo(obj.raw());
    };
}

// symbols from both clib.h and clibpp.h visible
```

Now, my wrapper is header only. So when someone includes `clibpp.h` they see symbols from both `clibpp.h` and `clib.h`. I want to avoid that. my idea is to include the `clib.h` header inside a namespace in the `clibpp.h` header to hide all the symbols.

```cpp
// clibpp.h
namespace clib {
    namespace detail {
        #include <clib.h>
    }
    std::string_view foo(const clib::obj_t& obj) {
        return detail::clib_foo(obj.raw());
    };
}

// symbols from only clibpp.h visible (apart from preprocessor definitions)
```

Is this a good idea or possible to do? Why doesn't anybody seem to do it?

Comment: Due to the macro include guards in the C header, if your client decides do include `clibpp.h` *before* `clib.h`, it would render the latter useless. This would be very confusing for the client, as he doesn't know that the original C functions are now inside some `detail` namespace! The other way, if the client includes the C header first, your code would not compile, as your include would be without effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a good idea or possible to do?

No, that won't work because the C library - for obvious reasons - doesn't define the functions etc. within that namespace.

> Why doesn't anybody seem to do it?

Because it doesn't work.

---

If you give up the desire to have a header-only wrapper library, then you can avoid "leaking" the C header since you could include it only within a translation unit of the wrapper library.

Note that this still doesn't solve all problems with name clashes since One Definition Rule applies across translation unit boundaries. If you link with a C library, then the external names of that library cannot be used by anything else. Hiding the C header does prevent macro-pollution.